# Django models with key and multiple value choices

Tags: python, django, postgresql

im trying to work my way into making an api oriented webapp with Django and i wanted to create a model where i can choose a day and a time for that day. So my first thought was to make a model with an atttibute that can stored set day with a set time, this last one being of multiple choice, like a dictionary or something. My motive is to save those values as attributes in my DB but i dont really know if thats possible! Thx a lot beforehand.

Something like this came to my mind:

class Reservation(models.Model):
reservation = ({'monday':[10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17], 'tusday':[10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17], 'friday':[10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17]})

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install django-jsonfield
```

Now, create a model in models.py, eg: −

```
import jsonfield
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Reservation(models.Model):
   reservations = jsonfield.JSONField()
```

Another option is create two separate models for Reservation & Time(Slots).